# App crash on rebuild without any change using apktool and apklab

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali, apktool

I am trying to rebuild apk after decompiling using apktool and apklab but app crash on splash screen. Following exceptions occur in logcat

```
Error updating last accessed time for {Google Sans, wdth 100.0, wght 400, ital 0.0, bestEffort false}. [CONTEXT service_id=132 ]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:1071)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:763)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:380)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:896)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1897)
    at ambs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):5)
    at aasm.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at aasm.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at aaxs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

UID for network attribution might be misset for tag 805307399 [CONTEXT service_id=39 ]
cquw: FULL
    at d.K(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at amek.a(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):12)
    at aoyl.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):8)
    at aoyc.d(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):1)
    at aoyh.a(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at aoyc.b(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):5)
    at aoyc.execute(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):8)
    at aoyc.execute(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at anka.h(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):46)
    at anjv.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at aasm.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at aasm.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at aaxs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

UID for network attribution might be misset for tag 805306624 [CONTEXT service_id=39 ]
cquw: FULL
    at d.K(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at amek.a(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):12)
    at aoyl.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):8)
    at aoyl.b(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at aaxi.a(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.social.c.d(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.social.c.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):5)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.social.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.social.d.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.social.k.call(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):12)
    at cuna.a(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at cuma.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at cunb.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at aasm.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at aasm.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at aaxs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Error inserting flex_time=0 job_id=-1 period=2000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=231015000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1680067117185 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:983)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1701)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1596)
    at blji.f(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):53)
    at blib.n(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blib.u(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):20)
    at blib.h(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blds.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):9)
    at aasm.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at aasm.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at aaxs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2023-03-29 10:18:37.224 12990-15442 Finsky                  pid-12990                            I  [70665] afts.r(8): Package com.google.android.gms is verified.
2023-03-29 10:18:37.345  2664-15752 NetworkScheduler        pid-2664                             W  Error inserting flex_time=9000 job_id=-1 period=20000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=231015000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1680067117341 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:983)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1701)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1596)
    at blji.f(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):53)
    at blib.n(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blib.u(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):20)
    at blib.h(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blds.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):9)
    at aasm.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at aasm.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at aaxs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2023-03-29 10:18:37.432  2664-14907 NetworkScheduler        pid-2664                             W  Error inserting flex_time=9000 job_id=-1 period=20000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=231015000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1680067117427 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:983)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1701)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1596)
    at blji.f(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):53)
    at blib.n(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blib.u(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):20)
    at blib.h(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blds.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):9)
    at aasm.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at aasm.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at aaxs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)


2023-03-29 10:18:37.564  2664-15908 NetworkScheduler        pid-2664                             W  Error inserting flex_time=9000 job_id=-1 period=20000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=231015000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1680067117553 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:983)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1701)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1596)
    at blji.f(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):53)
    at blib.n(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blib.u(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):20)
    at blib.h(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):3)
    at blds.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):9)
    at aasm.c(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):6)
    at aasm.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at aaxs.run(:com.google.android.gms@231015038@23.10.15 (150406-517566699):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2023-03-29 10:18:37.584 15757-15810 System                  pid-15757                            W  Ignoring header If-None-Match because its value was null.
```

Comment: If I remember correctly apps using certain Google services have to be registered by packageName and signer cert in Google Play console. By recompiling and resigning them the app does not match the registered values and a lot of things can go wrong.May be this is the reason for the abnormal behavior.

Comment: Did you signed and zipaligned the rebuild apk?